# Calculate the localization $(\{f:f(0)f(1)\ne 0\})^{-1}(\mathbb{C}[x])$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, ring-theory, localization

> Calculate the localization $S^{-1}R$ where $R=\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $S=\{f:f(0)f(1)\ne0\}$.

The problem isn't that I don't know how to solve it, but that I don't understand the question; A localization is defined by $\{f/g:f\in R, g\in S\}$ and $$a/b=c/d\iff\exists t\in R, 0=t(ad-bc)$$ (We can observe that $0\notin S$).

I don't really understand what should I calculate: In my eyes the localization is exactly $$\{f/g:f\in R, g\in S\}$$

Comment: It's that set up to the equivalence you wrote above.  Looks like it's rational functions without a vertical asymptote at 0 or 1.  The equivalence part is basically saying you can write every such function in the form $\frac{a(x)}{b(x)},$ where the two share no common factors in $\mathbb{C}[x]$.  (By the way, you don't need the (nonzero!) $t$ in your condition for integral domains, as $t(ad-bc)=0 \implies ad-bc = 0$.)